# error while trying to decrypt using azure vault certificate key: "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

I am trying to decrypt a encrypted string through C# code and azure key vault certificate key, the encryption part works fine but while decrypting, an exception occurs saying : "`Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`", "`Operation decrypt is not permitted on this key.`"

I have allowed all the permissions while registering this to Azure AD "App registrations" option from the AD blade. Is there any other place where I need to add any more permissions. Have followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application) to setup the Certificate and association with AD.

A line of the code I am using for decryption:

```
var decryptedData = kv.DecryptAsync(key.Key.Kid,JsonWebKeyEncryptionAlgorithm.RSAOAEP, encryptedTextNew).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If any one has done this, please write back in the comment, will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my situation is difference, but I'm going to drop some detail here just in case someone runs into the same problem.
I created a certificate (note: a certificate, not a key) on Azure Key Vault UI and used it for encrypt/decrypt and got the *Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'* error.

I tried to create a new certificate but this time I checked all the Advanced Policy Configuration options (you should only check the options you need though) and the new one worked for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

As I have tested, It seems that you do not configure the `Access Policy` in Key Vault for your application, to access keys or to process encryption/decryption.

[image]

Also, please have a check that if you add the role assignments of app registered to azure keyvault.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.thomas-zuehlke.de/2018/03/using-azure-key-vault/) which I have a test and it works fine.

Comment: Hi Joey, Thank you for the solution, I had already tried giving the full Key permissions to the vault through Access policies. After your comment, I tried the second step i.e. Access Control (IAM) for my Id, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if you try to use this kind of certificate in a Logic app with AS2Decode.
The error you will get then is:

- Integration account operation failed with status code: Forbidden and
  error KeyVaultOperationFailed : Communication with key vault
  '..........KeyVault' failed. Please authorize logic apps to perform
  operations on key vault by granting access for the logic apps service
  principal '7cd684f4-8a78-49b0-91ec-6a35d38739ba' for 'list', 'get',
  'decrypt' and 'sign' operations.

Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Make sure that during certificate upload or generation, you set the Data encipherment option in Advanced Policy Configuration. This can only be done during initial set-up. Changing it later does not work.

[Advanced Policy Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjQyA.png)